# Reading Firefox Bookmarks

Tags: c++, winapi, firefox, sqlite, bookmarks

Apparently, latest Firefox versions stores its bookmarks in a file called 'places.sqlite'. Like a browser can import the bookmarks from another browser, I would want to import the bookmarks to a file, but I need to know what would you need to do it?

Comment: `places.sqlite` **is** a file.  Do you mean that you want to export your bookmarks so that you can then import them elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is an embedded, serverless, relational database. Besides the mentioned ODBC drivers, it has [its own C API](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [SyncPlaces](http://www.andyhalford.com/syncplaces/index.html) Firefox extension, some kind of successor of the old [Bookmarks Synchronizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14) which is no longer maintained.

I use it to keep my bookmarks and cached passwords on Firefox on several computers in sync.

The file format it uses for export is [XBEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBEL), an XML based format, which was originally designed for a Python bookmarks management program, and which you might probably be able to use in your C++ program.

In principle, if you link to the [SQLite library](http://sqlite.org/), you can access `*.sqlite` files directly using SQL. Or, if it's a one shot program, you can try [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) to open such a file and export the tables to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQLite DBC driver. http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/